# Why does lightroom smart collection by capture date include wrong dates?

Tags: lightroom

In Lightroom Classic (20220128144), I created this simple smart collection using a capture date range:

[image: smart collection on capture date range]

Why is it including many, many images with dates outside the specified range?

[image: example pic wrong date]

Comment: Have you try to update LR, current version is 20220128 and I do not see such problem?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, I am now on latest and still have this problem.

Comment: If possible, can you perhaps check if the 2013 image has a 2005 date somewhere in the EXIF? You can e.g. check it for example [here](http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi).
And to be sure, there are not other rules in this Smart Collection?